# The representation of an empty argument in a "call"

Tags: r, reflection, argument-passing

What kind of animal is an empty argument? Consider the following piece of code.

```
> f <- function(...) match.call()
> l <- as.list(f(,3))
> l
[[1]]
f

[[2]]


[[3]]
[1] 3

> typeof(l[[2]])
[1] "symbol"

> identical(l[[2]],``)
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name

> as.character(l[[2]])
[1] ""
```

What sorcery is that?

Comment: It's an empty name/smybol which is used to represent missing values: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#names

Comment: @hadley: Thanks. How can i check for such a missing value? I tried missing(l[[2]]), but it gave me an error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If looks like `l[[2]]`'s value is a special object: the empty symbol. Some facts about the empty symbol (speculated based on casual experimentation).

(1) The empty symbol is a symbol:

```
> is.symbol(l[[2]])
[1] TRUE
```

(2) The empty symbol cannot be created explicitly:

```
> as.name("")
Error in as.name("") : attempt to use zero-length variable name
> ``
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> quote()
Error in quote() : 0 arguments passed to 'quote' which requires 1
```

(3) The only way to create an empty symbol is by `quote`-ing a function call and passing an empty argument, e.g.:

```
> c <- quote(f(,0))
> d <- quote(f(x, n=, 0))
```

The empty symbol can now be accessed thus: `c[[2]]`, `d$n`, `as.list(d)[[3]]`

(4) The empty value is unique and does not equal any other symbol:

```
> identical(c[[2]], d$n)
[1] TRUE

> identical(c[[2]], `a`)
[1] FALSE
```

(5) The empty symbol cannot be assigned to a standalone variable. If assigned to such a variable, the variable is actually assigned the "missing argument" value:

```
> x <- d$n
> missing(x)
[1] TRUE
> missing(d$n)
Error in missing(d$n) : invalid use of 'missing'
```

However, the empty symbol can be assigned to a list slot:

```
> p <- list(`a`, k=`b`)
> p[[1]] <- d$n
> p$k <- c[[2]]

> identical(p[[1]], d$n)
[1] TRUE

> identical(p[[1]], p[[2]])
[1] TRUE
```

And it can be passed as a function argument:

```
> h <- function(x) identical("", d$n)
> h(c[[2]])
[1] TRUE
```

When passed as a function argument, the argument is not considered to be missing:

```
> h2 <- function(x) missing(x)
> h2(c[[2]])
[1] FALSE
```

But compare

```
> h2(x)
[1] TRUE
```

(6) The character value of the empty symbol is the empty string:

```
> identical("", as.character(d$n))
[1] TRUE
```

(7) There is no primitive function that checks whether a value is the empty symbol. To check whether a value is the empty symbol, its character representation needs to be compared to the empty string:

```
> is.symbol(d$n) && identical("", as.character(d$n))
[1] TRUE
```

---

***Appendix***

Here are a number of function definitions to facilitate the creation and identification of empty symbols and "missing argument" objects.

```
> isEmptySymbol
function(x) is.symbol(x) && identical("", as.character(x))

> EmptySymbol
function() (quote(f(,)))[[2]]

> isMissingArgObject
function(x) {
if ("x" %in% names(match.call())) return (missing(x))
stop("An argument must be supplied.") }

> MissingArgObject
function() quote(expr=)
```

Comment: For 4, you should do `is.symbol(d$n) && identical(as.character(d$n), ""))`

Comment: Good explanation, btw.  The trick with the empty function argument is neat.

Comment: Did you read the link I pointed you to? I think the best way to create these objects is with `quote(expr = )`. Unfortunately the obvious way to test `identical(x, quote(expr = ))` doesn't work. As well as your solution, you could write a little C code to check for `R_MissingArg`

Comment: @hadley: This stuff is very confusing because two essential principles of R are violated here: (1) That every variable can hold any value, (2) That whenever a variable `exists`, it has a value. I find this to be bad language design.

Comment: I don't see how either of those principles are violated - the MissingArg object exists, it just doesn't do anything useful when you try and access it

Comment: @hadley: Contrast the following two code segments that illustrate the two points I made.

`> str(quote(expr=))`

***vs.***

`> x <- quote(expr=); print(exists("x")); str(x)`

Comment: Yes, x exists, but due to the special behaviour of MissingArg, it throws an error when it you try and access it if it's bound to a variable. This is confusing, but in general R is not referentially transparent because of non-standard evaluation.