# R function calls, ... and missing values

Tags: r, arrays, variadic-functions

I am trying to implement my own array type in R and want the semantics to match the builtin arrays. For this I have to be able to do handle calls like:

```
my.array(1:9, c(3, 3, 3))
x[1:2, 1, 2]
x[,,3]
```

I am implementing this as:

```
`[.my.array` <- function(x, ..., drop = TRUE) {
  os <- range_to_offset_shape(...)
  result <- getindex(x, offset = os$offset, shape = os$shape)
  if(drop) result <- handle_drop(result)
  return(result)
}
```

where

```
range_to_offset_shape <- function(...) {
  i <- list(...)

  offset <- sapply(i, function(x) x[1])
  shape <- sapply(i, function(x) x[length(x)] - x[1] + 1)
  return(list(offset = offset, shape = shape))
}
```

This works fine, as long as there are no missing arguments. To make this work I have to substitute the missing arguments in `...` with `1:dim(x)[i]`, what is the best way of doing this? Other solutions are also welcome!

Comment: Your function should have parameters `i` and `j`. Then you could do `if (missing(i)) {...}`. Use `[.data.frame` as a guideline.

Comment: the problem is that arrays can have a variable number of dimensions

Comment: Well, then check if your `i` list has any empty elements.

Comment: the call to `list(...)` produces an error if there are missing elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility for approaching this:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/20906150/1412059
isEmptySymbol <- function(x) is.symbol(x) && identical("", as.character(x))

foo <- function(...) {
  i <- as.list(match.call())[-1] #call before evaluation

  #replace empty symbols (here with 0 as an example)
  i[vapply(i, isEmptySymbol, FUN.VALUE = TRUE)] <- 0 

  #evaluate all list elements
  lapply(i, eval)
}

x <- 2
foo(1, , x)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks, works. For style points: If you want the `...` to be handled by another function, this doesn't work, e.g. `bar <- function(x, ...) { new_idx <- foo(...); baz(x, new_idx) }`

Comment: Can't you do `do.call(baz, foo(...))`?

Comment: the problem is that inside `foo`, the symbol names get changed to `..1`, `..2`, ...