# Select all columns in array via a variable in R

Tags: r, arrays

Say that we have an array `a` with dimensions 10, 10, 10 or something. We can select columns of `a` via a variable e.g. `cols = c("colName1","colName2"); a[,cols,]`, etc.

Now let's say that we want to select all columns of `a`, but want to do so via a variable as before. That is, we may want to return `a[,,1]`, but using the variable `cols`. So we want `a[,cols,1]` to return the same as `a[,,1]`. What should we set `cols` to do this this? Is there something better/ more generic than `cols=1:dim(a)[2]`? I tried using `NULL`, but this didn't work, and just returned nothing.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: See here for information on how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: Also somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904827/the-representation-of-an-empty-argument-in-a-call