# Can an R function ever return nothing, as in []?

Tags: r, null

Anyone who has played around with R for a little while knows that there is a a difference between genuinely nothing and any of `NULL`, `0`, objects of length 0:

```
> a<-list(1,2,3,4)
> a[]#"Genuinely nothing"
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

> a[NULL]
list()
> a[0]
list()
> a[integer(0)]
list()
```

This first case has my interest. Is there any way to make an R function return what I've called "genuinely nothing", so that `a[foo]` returns all of `a` and interacts with subassignment like `a[]` does? I'm aware of equivalent behavior, like `a[TRUE]`, but I want to know if it's possible to have a function return what I'm calling "genuinely nothing". Presumably, the example that I've given must be feeding some sort of argument to `[`, so it should exist in R somewhere.

Comment: This might shed some light on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904827/the-representation-of-an-empty-argument-in-a-call/20906150 But basically there's no object in user space that you can easily pass that will act like an empty argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Hadley in the comments of the [above mentionned post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20906150/13513328):

```r
a <- list(1,2,3,4)

foo <- function() {quote(expr=)} 
a[foo()]

#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 4
```

Comment: Maybe that will work in terms of this specific use with the `[` operator, but it doesn't work in the general case for all functions: `b <- function(x=6) print(x)` where `b(foo)` is not the same as `b()`

Comment: @MrFlick, you're right, as the empty object exists, the `b` function doesn't use its default argument value. This is genuinely empty but not genuinely nothing ;-)

Comment: That's why it might be better just to mark this as a dup since this is just a copy of the information that's already on the other question and the other question has a fuller discussion of the topic.

Comment: @MrFlick, agree